# jQuery AJAX: mixed URL variables and POST data (ColdFusion)

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, post, coldfusion

I have a page with a replaceable div which gets used as part of a user interface for managing forms for updating information about any one of several projects.

So there is a list of projects, each one has an ID from the database, and each has a "Manage Project" link. When the user clicks that link, the AJAX replaces the div with a form where the user enters a progress update & other info into form elements.

That form has a submit button which AJAX-es in a third page where I'd like to run the update queries and print confirmation info. I created an AJAX controller ColdFusion page with a switch statement to determine which page to load to the div based on a switch statement on a variable in the URL. The URL variable is set by jQuery on click depending on which link is clicked (i.e. ?ajax=manage for this one.)

I haven't had any trouble passing URL variables this way but now that I'm using text boxes I want to send the form data to the third page as serialized POST data. But I can't figure out how to serialize the form and send it with the other URL variables with $.ajax()

**The first page**

```
<input type="hidden" id="selection">
<a href="" onClick="return false;">
    <span style="font-size: 1.3em;" class="manage" 
        <!--- PROJ_CDE is the project's unique ID in the database--->
        onClick="$('##selection').val('#PROJ_CDE#');">
        Manage Project
    </span>
</a>
```

**First AJAX controller**

```
$('.manage').click(function()
{
    // Gets the project code to pull AJAX content for
    var project = $('#selection').val();
    // Send the project code & chosen link to AJAX controller
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/ajax/ajax_ctrl.cfm?ajax=manage&project=" + project,
        success: function(returnedData)
        {
            // Tells JS which project to switch content out for
            $('#replaceDiv' + '_' + $('#selection').val()).html(returnedData);
        }
    });
});
```

**ColdFusion AJAX controller**

```
<cfset ajax = url.ajax>
<cfswitch expression="#ajax#">
    <cfcase value="manage">
        <cfinclude template="manage.cfm"></cfcase>
    <cfcase value="manage_sbmt">
        <cfinclude template="manage_sbmt.cfm"></cfcase>
    <cfcase value="main">
        <cfinclude template="main.cfm"></cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase>
        Nothing loaded!</cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
```

**Second page (form)**

```
<script src="js/ajax_ctrl.js"></script>
<cfset project = url.project>
<form id="updates" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="selection" value="changeme">
    Update Progress<br />
    <div id="hidden_prgrs"><br />
        <textarea id="upd_prgrs_text" cols="75" rows="8"></textarea><br /><br />
        <hr />
    </div><br />
    <br />
    <span class="manage_sbmt" onClick="$('##selection').val('#project#');">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Update Project!" onClick="return false;">
    </span>
</form>
```

**Second AJAX controller**

```
$('.manage_sbmt').click(function()
{
    var project = $('#selection').val();
    var form = $('#updates');
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/ajax/ajax_ctrl.cfm?ajax=manage_sbmt&project=" + project,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#replaceDiv' + '_' + $('#selection').val()).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Which hits the CF switch page again & loads manage_sbmt, where I'm just trying to dump the variable scope & get it to print the textarea input.

In my second AJAX controller, in $.ajax(), I've been trying to use the data argument to serialize & pass the full form, but it doesn't work. I thought this would accomplish it, but when I alert(data); I get weird output that seems to be random HTML stuff.

```
data: form.serialize(),
```

Why is the form not posting to the third page? Is it even possible to do this with $.ajax()? I want to avoid encoding the whole text box as a URL since there is a character limit, and for other obvious reasons...

Comment: Your textarea doesn't have a `name` attribute so its not going to get serialized.

Comment: Thanks! I added that in, but it's still not posting unfortunately. I wonder if it has to do with the form itself not being submitted? Since I call return: false; on the submit button to avoid posting it back to the start (index.cfm) I never actually "submit" the form, just perform the $.ajax() on click...

Comment: WOOHOO! I got it. That actually DID work! The problem was that I was just dumping the #variables# scope, not #form#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Musa had the right answer. I needed to add a name attribute to the form elements, then when I did cfdump var="#form#" it showed up.